# Iterating over the last dimensions of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, iteration

Consider the following snippet:

```
a = np.ones((2,2,2,2,2))
for example in a:
    for row in example:
        for col in row:
            for box in col:
                print (box.shape)
```

Having so many nested `for`s makes for some very ugly code.

How can I get the same effect with only one explicit iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape your array:

```
for box in a.reshape(16,2):
    print(box.shape)
```

---

A general solution:

```
for box in a.reshape(np.prod(a.shape[:-1]), a.shape[-1]):
     print(box.shape)
```

which will always iterate over one-before-the-last dimension of `a`.

Comment: Any way of doing this without referencing the shape of a, only the axis we want to iterate over?

Comment: @Jsevillamol See my update for a general solution :)